# XAML gridview listview with grouping cells

Tags: xaml, gridview, merge

I have a xaml gridview inside a listview. 
My databinding happens in code behind.
The datasource is a dataset which is populated from sql.
The dataset has 6 columns. A 'Type', a 'NUM' and 4 lines which contains the address.
I want to display the address lines within a single cell in the gridview, each line below the other.

xaml

```
<Grid x:Name="grid1">
<StackPanel>

        <ListView Name="listview1" Margin="10,10,10,10" IsTextSearchEnabled="True" TextSearch.TextPath="Addendum_Type" Height="400" BorderBrush="#FFA8CC7B">

        <ListView.View>

            <GridView ColumnHeaderToolTip="Addendum Master">

                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Addendum_Type}" Header="TYPE" Width="150"/>

                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Addendum_Number}" Header="NUM" Width="150"/>

                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Line1}" Header="1" Width="150"/>

                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Line2}" Header="2" Width="150"/>

                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Line3}" Header="3" Width="150"/>

                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Line4}" Header="4" Width="150"/>


            </GridView>

        </ListView.View>

    </ListView>

</StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

How can I combine those four lines into one cell?
[image: This is what I want the Gridview to display]

And so here is what I tried

```
        <ListView Name="listview1" Margin="10,10,10,10" IsTextSearchEnabled="True" TextSearch.TextPath="Addendum_Type" Height="400" BorderBrush="#FFA8CC7B">

        <ListView.View>

            <GridView ColumnHeaderToolTip="Addendum Master">

                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Addendum_Type}" Header="TYPE" Width="150"/>

                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Addendum_Number}" Header="NUM" Width="150"/>

                    <GridViewColumn Width="150">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Line1}" Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Line2}" Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Line3}" Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Line4}" Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </GridViewColumn>

            </GridView>

        </ListView.View>

    </ListView>

</StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

But that just reads the gridview to look like

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it right by doing this.

```
<ListView Name="listview1" Margin="10,10,10,10" IsTextSearchEnabled="True" TextSearch.TextPath="Addendum_Type" Height="400" BorderBrush="#FFA8CC7B">

        <ListView.View>

            <GridView ColumnHeaderToolTip="Addendum Master">

                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Addendum_Type}" Header="TYPE" Width="150"/>

                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Addendum_Number}" Header="NUM" Width="150"/>

                    <GridViewColumn Width="500">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                    <Label Content="{Binding Path=Line1}"></Label>
                                    <Label Content="{Binding Path=Line2}"></Label>
                                    <Label Content="{Binding Path=Line3}"></Label>
                                    <Label Content="{Binding Path=Line4}"></Label>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>

                    </GridViewColumn>

            </GridView>

        </ListView.View>
```